# How to get all the keys  (only keys) from dictionary object without going through for each loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, dictionary, oop

I checking to see if we have any way to return all the keys  to array  without using the for each loop  (there is no constraint for me to use for each loop i am just looking is there any other way)

Thanks in advance

Comment: see related [how-to-get-the-list-of-key-in-dictionary-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276763/how-to-get-the-list-of-key-in-dictionary-c-sharp?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the list of keys in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276763/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-keys-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I'm not certain from your wording whether you want the keys or the values. Either way, it's pretty straightforward. Use either the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx) or [`Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx) property of the dictionary and the [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension method.

```
var arrayOfAllKeys = yourDictionary.Keys.ToArray();

var arrayOfAllValues = yourDictionary.Values.ToArray();
```

Comment: hm... It doesn't work for me - System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,MyClass1>.KeyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,MyClass1>.KeyCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Chiz: `ToArray` is a LINQ extension method so you'll need a `using System.Linq;` directive at the top of your code.

Answer (score 5):

You want the keys or the values?

The keys you can get like this:

```
dictionary.Keys.ToArray();
```

The values you can get like this;

```
dictionary.Values.ToArray();
```

This ToArray method is from System.Linq.Enumerable.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] myKeys;
myKeys = myDictionary.Keys.ToArray();
```

Untested, but I don't see why it would work.

Comment: This code: `var arrayOfAllKeys = yourDictionary.Keys.ToArray();` Posted by LukeH is better , because this code less and more understandable.
and accessible value via under code :
`arrayOfAllKeys.[0].ToString();`
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:-

```
dict.Select(p => $"Keys in dict: {p.Key}")
```