# Visual Studio Does not recognize System.Linq

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, declaration

I created this program and C# and it worked correctly a few weeks ago.
Now, I copied all of this code to a another project I am working on.  I added it to a brand new C# Class inside of the project I am working on.  Visual Studio didn't recognize the assembly references that say "not found" in the comments.

This is just bizarre since they were found in the previous program.  Does anyone know why Visual Studio can't find these assembly references.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;    //not found
using System.Text;
using XML_Creator;     //not found
using System.Xml.Linq; //not found
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Have the references been added to the project?

Comment: Do you have `System.Xml.Linq.dll` referenced in your new project?

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: I am using framework 4.0

Comment: @user3670048 The question would be: which target version of the .NET framework is the project using?

Comment: yeah.. you are right.. Target framework.. because it does not work with versions below 3.5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An educated guess: It's probably the .NET framework target version of the new project.

[System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) was introduced on .NET Framework 3.5.

Go to Project -> Properties -> Application and check the Target Framework property. It's probably a target framework prior to 3.5

Comment: This might not actually be the case. My target framework in the project properties was showing 4.0, but I am working in a Web project and the Web.config didn't have a "targetFramework" attribute on the <compilation> tag. Adding 'targetFramework="4.0"', closing the project, and reopening it fixed it for me. You can also toggle the properties to 3.5 and back to 4.0, but it takes more time.

Answer (score 18):

You need to add refrence to system.Core.

[image]

Comment: Why System.Core.dll rather than System.Linq.dll?

Comment: @xr280xr If you are still curious, it's because the System.Linq namespace definition is actually in the System.Core assembly (in System.Core.dll).

Comment: In VS2019 (.NET 4.7.X), this reference cannot be (explicitly) added, it fails with "A reference to 'System.Core' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system"

Comment: Completely new Clean MVC project .net 4.8, gives me this error too. I tried just about everything in here.
Coincidentally; if I make a new MVC project in VB, I dont get missing Linq error. Go figure

Comment: There are tons of reasons, why one has to stick to .NET framework, instead of Core, typically it's out of his/her hands. In addition to that, you cannot change a .NET framework to Core without quite some work. So even though this might work, it's not very helpful, IMHO.

Answer (score 10):

- Step 1) Go to your Project **Solution Explorer** and Select
  **References**
- Step 2) Right click it on **References** and Select **Add Reference...** a form will appear
- Step 3) Search **linq** on Search bar
- Step 4) Now Select/tick the **System.XML.Linq** checkbox
- Step 5) Click **Ok**

Comment: Somebody already mentioned this...but I when I do this there is no search bar...and I cannot find System.XML.linq

Comment: You need a reference to **System.Core** for **Linq** to work in .Net framework 4

Comment: You just Saved my day

Answer (score 4):

If your file is in App_Code folder, try moving it to another folder. For me its solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to right click on the solution in Solution Explorer and add a reference to System.Xml.Linq and/or System.Linq in Project Properties.

This has hit me several times - I see it a lot with System.Configuration as well. (For some reason those two references seem to be particularly picky)

Comment: Well now I am running into the problem that System.Linq and System.XML.Linq isn't in the browser ... :(

Comment: Please note that System.Linq namespace is in the System.Core assembly, not System.Xml.Linq

Comment: This did work, I thought I was using the 4.0 framework, when it was set to 2.0... so this didn't show System.XML.Linq

Answer (score 1):

For me I tried this and worked:

PROJECT==>Add Reference ==> Browse ==> 
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_netfx35linq-system.core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_6161fc35ed136622\System.core.dll

Or

you can simply find the System.core.dll using windows search on Os System Drive

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I upgraded my asp.net project to .NET Framework 4.5.x and it worked. I did tried 4.5.1 first and then later 4.5.0 and both seem to be helping.