# VS Code (Mac) missing light bulb?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code in Mac, for C#. In the picture below, I'm missing the light bulb that recommends I'm missing System.Linq. Where is the option to enable the light bulb? I have the C# extension by Microsoft installed.

[image: no lightbulb]

I know there should be a light bulb because my VS Code for my Windows has it.

Edited: Just found out that I can see this behavior sometimes in my VS Code Windows too :\

Comment: @D-johnAnshani None of those are for VS Code. And none of it are relevant.

Comment: Do you have the `.net Core Framework` installed on your Mac?

Comment: @Smartis Yes, 2.1.4. Just in case I did the wrong thing: I run dotnet --version on Terminal.

Comment: @buffjape Most probably yes, since I use full VS for bigger solutions. Just that it's annoying not having the editor add all the missing namespace while I'm doing quick trial and error. So I'm the only one that have this or this is a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

USE

> ⌘ + .

AS suggested [Here](http://www.arungudelli.com/microsoft/visual-studio-code-keyboard-shortcut-cheat-sheet-windows-mac-linux/), it's quick fix

Comment: I'm getting "No code actions available". No suggestion to add missing namespace...

Comment: is "using system.linq;" already added? if not have you tried adding it manually? if not this might be this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659934/visual-studio-does-not-recognize-system-linq

Comment: It's working if I add it manually. My issue is that the light bulb doesn't appear to suggest to me that I'm missing the namespace. Tried with Collection.Generics.List, doesn't appear too.