# C# application with random questions can't add answers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project where I want to make a random quiz with random questions and answers. I used a dictionary to do this and I succeeded in making the questions and answers and in displaying a random one.

Now I want to add specific answers per question asked. I figured this should be done by a dictionary also but I don't know how to make this work.

I already made the random generator, the questions and answers (tkey and tvalue)

So now I only need to add a part where you have specific answers per questions and a way to detect if the questions are wrong or right, this can be done by a if and a else statement but I'm not experienced enough to know how to implement all these functions.

This is what I have right now

```
class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        //maak een dictionary aan
        Console.WriteLine("Quiz");

        Dictionary<int, string> Questions = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        //voeg vragen toe 
        //key koppelen aan vraag
        Questions.Add(11, "Vraag1?");
        Questions.Add(12, "Vraag2?");
        Questions.Add(13, "Vraag3?");
        Questions.Add(14, "Vraag4?");
        Questions.Add(15, "Vraag5?");

        Dictionary<int, string> answers = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        List<int> keylist = new List<int>(); // string naar int converten
        keylist = Questions.Keys.ToList();

        Random rand = new Random(); //maak random aan
        int countKeys = Questions.Keys.Count();
        int randomIndex = rand.Next(0, countKeys);

        Console.WriteLine(Questions.ElementAt(randomIndex).Key); //geef een random index en de gekoppelde key daaraan

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("You answered: " + input);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me by telling me / helping me make a way to add specific answers to these questions?

Comment: Would you like to map the real answer to the question or would you like to store the answer of the user next to the question?

Comment: Create a `class Quiz` with `public string Question {get;set;}` and `public string Answer {get;set;}` then in your dictionary instead of `<int, string>` keep `<int, Quiz>`

Comment: Should the user type the answer, or select it from a list ? (like in a multiple choice questionaire)

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I would rather create a `Dictionary<string, string>` that stores a question as key with it's answer as value, then select a random key

Comment: Also, if you use the `class Quiz` as above the answer could either be a string or, easier for checking, a list of alternate answers to enable multiple choice

Comment: @Cid it should type the answer and then if its right it shoudl display a new question and if it is wrong it should close the application

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, string>` to store the questions as **key** and the answer as **value**

Then, get the [list of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276763/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-keys-in-a-dictionary) and [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt) it, to finally iterate through that list.

In example ([fiddle to the below code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4MzBJ9)) :

```
private static Random rng = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1)
    {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var quizz = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "What is the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything ?", "42" },
        { "What is your name ?", "Sir Arthur, king of the Britons" },
        { "What is your quest ?", "To seek the Holy Grail" },
        { "What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?", "What do you mean ? An African or European swallow ?" }
    };
    var questions = quizz.Keys.ToList();
    questions.Shuffle();

    foreach (var question in questions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question);
        if (Console.ReadLine() != quizz[question])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You failed");
            Console.ReadLine();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nice !");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put answer for each key from Questions.

```
foreach(var item in Questions) {
    answers.Add(item.Key, "answer")
}
```

store the specific answer by same random index of question into another variable

```
var askingQuestion = Questions.ElementAt(randomIndex);
var answerOfAskingQuestion = answers.ElementAt(randomIndex);
```

Display the question to read answer from console

```
Console.WriteLine(answerOfAskingQuestion.value);
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Now compare the input with value of answerOfAskingQuestion

```
if (input.ToLower().Equals(answerOfAskingQuestion.Value.ToLower()) {
    // given answer is correct
    // display "your answer is correct"
    Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct");
} else { 
    // answer is wrong
    // display "incorrect"
    Console.WriteLine("Your answer is wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a "Question" class containing the question text, a list of answers and the correct answer. So your Questions dictionary should be:

```
Dictionary<int, Question> Questions = new Dictionary<int, Question>();
```